# How to modify subelement of multidimensional array in foreach iteration

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, reference, foreach

I am attempting to modify the contents of the first subelement in each array element of a multidimensional array, however, if I pass said element by reference I get an error that "&" is not expected.  Do I need to ditch the foreach ($arr as list ()) syntax and revert to a standard for loop and access with a counter variable?

```
foreach ($transactions as list(&$student, &$tyID)) {

    $query = "SELECT $column
              FROM student
              WHERE stUserID=$student";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $userHID);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $student = $userHID;
            $tyID = $transType[$tyID];
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}
```

Edit: Updated code, I actually need to modify the first two subelements of each array in the transactions array.

Comment: What do you have in transactions array only student id's ?? . What do you mean by modify the sub element ??

Comment: transactions contains an array of transaction data (userID, type of transaction, debit, credit, etc.) the first element of which is a student identifier.  I am modifying this element based on who is viewing the page, if it is faculty it will be the student number, if it is a student viewing the page it will show an alias.  I am trying to perform all reformatting prior to output in a table. @Ninad

Comment: Then while getting the transaction table itself you perform the checks and get the array accordingly

Comment: @Ninad Sadly the table only contains a reference to a userID, I must then match that id against the id of another table to find the values I want.  The database design is outside of my control.  Is what I am asking to do beyond PHP's current capabilities?  I know this structure was only introduced in 5.5.

Comment: Then why are you using the reference to the elements from the transaction array just use simple foreach loop to get the desired ids and modify why using list ??

Comment: @Ninad I don't know if you're misunderstanding me or if I'm misunderstanding you.  List() is used as transactions is a multidimensional array.  I am constructing list with references with the theory that that will allow me to modify the value, but further research of list() makes that look like not an option.  I was hoping for a more elegant way of doing this but it looks like I might need a more standard (and ugly) looping approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do it in this way? Assumed the keys are same as the list variables

```
foreach ($transactions as &$transaction) {

    $query = "SELECT {$column}
              FROM student
              WHERE stUserID={$transaction['student']}";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $userHID);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $transaction['student'] = $userHID;
            $transaction['tyID'] = $transType[$transaction['tyID']];
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}
```

Comment: This essentially worked. I used list() because it gave me variables to use instead of ugly transaction[#] that I ended up having to use.  But otherwise this is still better than the for loop I would have otherwise needed.  Thank you.  I would up-vote if I had enough rep!

Comment: glad this helped, Now you can I suppose :)

Comment: Still 2 short!  Don't worry, @code-jaff, I'll get it as soon as I can.